# Data Binding multiple items in code on a listbox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, listbox

I have a `ListBox` in WPF that I am trying to bind a class to that is a list with 2 properties which are `FirstName` and `LastName`. I bind the `ItemSource` and `DisplayMemberPath` in XAML and all works fine.

I now need to do this in code but all I see is the list with the class name so the `DisplayMemberPath` is not being bound correctly.

```
Dim b1 As New Binding
b1.Source = dc.People

Dim b2 As New Binding
b2.Path = New PropertyPath("FirstName")

BindingOperations.SetBinding(myListBox, ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, b1)
BindingOperations.SetBinding(myListBox, ListBox.DisplayMemberPathProperty, b2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is set as a property of the `ListBox`, not a binding.

```
myListBox.DisplayMemberPath = "FirstName"
```